# Como obtener la respues de mercado despues de realizar un pago o rechazarlo en flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, mercadopago

aqui realizo la llamada a la funcion donde se va a abrir la aplicacion de mercado pago, una vez que haya finalizado la operacion en la aplicacion de mercado pago ya sea realizando el pago o rechanzadolo, la aplicacion debe de mostrar el mensaje correspondiente

```
validacion(){
   mensaje = await pagoOnlineProvider.abrirMercadoPago(_solicitudController.text, _numCuentaController.text, totalaPagar, listaRecibosDetalle);

      Navigator.of(context).pop();

      //ShowDialogPage.showMensajeDialog(context, "Resultado", mensaje, 1);

      PaymentResult result = await MercadoPagoMobileCheckout.startCheckout(
                                      publicKey,
                                      clientId,
                                    );
      
      print("El resultado despues del pago es: ");
      print(result.toString());
}
```

aqui armo las preferencias con los datos que voy a enviarle a mercado pago:

```
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> armarPreferencia(idCliente, montoTotal, titular, documento, idOrden) async {
    //var mp = MP('Client_ID', 'Client_Secret');

    var mp = MP(clientId, clientSecret);

    String? token = await mp.getAccessToken();

    var preference = {
      "items": [
        {
          "id" : idCliente,
          "title":"Pago Factura EDESE S.A.",
          "quantity": 1,
          "currency_id": "ARS",
          "unit_price": 10,
        }
      ],
      "payer": 
      [
        {
          "name":"Test",
          "Identification": 
          {
            "type": "DNI",
            "number": documento
          },
        }
      ],
      "payment_methods": 
      {
        "excluded_payment_types": 
        [
          {
            "id": "atm"
          },
          {
            "id": "ticket"
          }
        ],
    
      },
      "back_urls":
      {
        "success": mensaje = "Exito",
        "failure": mensaje = "Fallo",
        "pending": mensaje = "Pendiente",
      },
      
      "external_reference": idOrden,

    };
    var result = await mp.createPreference(preference);
    return result;
  }
```

aqui convoco a la funcion de armarprefenrecias y controlo si hay alguna respuesta, en caso de que conteste abro la aplicacion de mercado pago

```
  Future <String> abrirMercadoPago(idCliente, montoTotal, titular, documento, idOrden) async {

    armarPreferencia(idCliente, montoTotal, titular, documento, idOrden).then((result) 
    {

      if(result != null)
      {
        var respuesta = result['response'];
        abrirDireccion(respuesta['init_point']);
      }
      
    });

    return mensaje;

  }
```

en mi caso ya sea que el pago se realize o se cancele, la respuesta que obtengo es la siguiente:

PaymentResult(result: canceled, id: null, status: null, statusDetail: null, paymentMethodId: null, paymentTypeId: null, issuerId: null, installments: null, captured: null, liveMode: null, operationType: null, transactionAmount: null, errorMessage: null)

como puedo solucianar esto?